# View Port inconsistencies between browsers for Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I am building a website using the responsive framework [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) v5.5.0

I want to use their Reveal Modal to have an overlay pop up and display additional articles relating to the page they are on.

The reveal module works, but I've noticed inconsistencies. Chrome works fine, however in IE and Firefox the modal displayed a set amount of pixels from the top of the body instead of the top of the view port. As a result you have to scroll up to view the modal if the user has scrolled below the fold.

**What I've tried**

 This thread got me started on the right path

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/21450-reveal-modal-positioning-and-background-issues

So I first tried editing the Foundation.js file. Line 3901

ORIGINAL

```
   css.top = $(root_element).scrollTop() - el.data('offset') + 'px'; //adding root_element instead of window for scrolling offset if modal trigger is below the fold
```

REPLACEMENT

```
  css.top = $(window).scrollTop() - el.data('offset') + 'px';
```

This did not work. So I tried to fix it using CSS

```
    /*Learn More Overlay Fixes*/
.reveal-modal-bg{
    height:2000px !important;
    position:fixed;
}

.reveal-modal{position:fixed;

}
```

And this fixed the issue... in internet explorer and Firefox. Now chrome is displaying the image far below the middle of the screen like I want

Heres the fix in IE
[image: Internet Explorer]

But the result of Chrome
[image: Chrome]

And opera gives me even weirder results. Putting the modal very far below the view port of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change to the position on 5.5 that was fixed in the latest version. It only affected certain browsers. Now it has a smarter positioning so even if you open a modal triggered from the bottom of the page it will position properly.

Comment: I upgraded and it was fixed. Thank you!